# Process RGBA data efficiently using python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to process an **RGBA buffer (list of chars)**, and run "unpremultiply" on each pixel. The algorithm is `color_out=color*255/alpha`.

This is what I came up with:

```
def rgba_unpremultiply(data):
    for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
        a = ord(data[i+3])
        if a != 0:
            data[i] = chr(255*ord(data[i])/a)
            data[i+1] = chr(255*ord(data[i+1])/a)
            data[i+2] = chr(255*ord(data[i+2])/a)
    return data
```

It works but causes a major drawback in performance.

I'm wondering besides writing a C module, what are my options to optimize this particular function?

Comment: Probably it won't be faster than NumPy, but you could try using bytearray instead of a list of chars -- you won't need the expensive "char" and "ord" calls, as bytearray's elements are treated as numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of code [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) is great for.

```
import numpy

def rgba_unpremultiply(data):
    a = numpy.fromstring(data, 'B') # Treat the string as an array of bytes
    a = a.astype('I') # Cast array of bytes to array of uints, since temporary values needs to be larger than byte
    alpha = a[3::4] # Every 4th element starting from index 3
    alpha = numpy.where(alpha == 0, 255, alpha) # Don't modify colors where alpha is 0
    a[0::4] = a[0::4] * 255 // alpha # Operates on entire slices of the array instead of looping over each element
    a[1::4] = a[1::4] * 255 // alpha
    a[2::4] = a[2::4] * 255 // alpha
    return a.astype('B').tostring() # Cast back to bytes
```

Comment: I'll leave it to someone else to figure out a NumPy solution that 1) doesn't use 4 times as much memory as necessary 2) only does a single pass over the array, for better cache usage.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like numpy boosted the performance a lot. My test benchmark lowered from some 88s to 20s.

Comment: One more thing, would you please clarify why numpy didn't have to check for divide by zero situations?

Comment: Actually, I just forgot to include that :) Integer division by 0 gives 0 in NumPy by default (see e.g. [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html)), but that's not the same as your original code. It probably doesn't matter what color the pixels with alpha = 0 have though.

Comment: Added one line to avoid the division by zero.

Answer (score 2):

How big is data?  Assuming this is on python2.X Try using xrange instead of range so that you don't have to constantly allocate and reallocate a large list.

You could convert all the data to integers for working with them so you're not constantly converting to and from characters.

Look into using numpy to vectorize this: [Link](https://numpy.org/)  I suspect that simply storing the data as integers and using a numpy array will greatly improve the performance.

And another relatively simple thing you could do is write a little Cython:

http://wiki.cython.org/examples/mandelbrot

Basically Cython will compile your above function into C code with just a few lines of type hints.  It greatly reduces the barrier to writing a C extension.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a concrete answer, but some useful pointers might be:

- Python's [array module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)
- [numpy](https://numpy.org/)
- [OpenCV](https://web.archive.org/web/20130803074437/http://opencv.willowgarage.com:80/wiki/PythonInterface) if you have actual image data

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor things you can do, but I do not think you can improve a lot.

Anyway, here's some hint:

```
def rgba_unpremultiply(data):
    # xrange() is more performant then range, it does not precalculate the whole array
    for i in xrange(0, len(data), 4):
        a = ord(data[i+3])
        if a != 0:
            # Not sure about this, but maybe (c << 8) - c is faster than c*255
            # So maybe you can arrange this to do that
            # Check for performance improvement
            data[i] = chr(((ord(data[i]) << 8) - ord(data[i]))/a)
            data[i+1] = chr(255*ord(data[i+1])/a)
            data[i+2] = chr(255*ord(data[i+2])/a)
    return data
```

I've just make some dummy benchmark on << vs *, and it seems not to be markable differences, but I guess you can do better evaluation on your project.

Anyway, a c module may be a good thing, even if it does not seem to be "language related" the problem.

Comment: It looks like xrange isn't that different from range in my particular case. The benchmark is within marginal error.